# jQuery Form Field population after Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery and a little JSON API that I wrote to dynamically get MySQL Data upon the change Event of a Select field. Then I populate other form fields with the data I just acquired.

The following code works perfectly fine in Safari, but neither in Firefox (25.0.1), nor in Chrome (31.0.1650.63).

I am not getting any Errors threw tools like the Inspector. This already cost me a couple of hours, does anyone have an idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$('#day').change(function() {

$.getJSON("http://www.url.com/api/result.json?day=" + $('#day :selected').val() + "&position=" + $('#position :selected').val(),

    function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.field == "time") {
              $("#time").val(item.value);
            }
            else if (item.field == "heading") {
              $("#heading").val(item.value);
            }
            else if (item.field == "description") {
              $("#description").val(item.value);
            }
            else if (item.field == "details") {
              $("#details").val(item.value);
            }
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

A sample JSON response would look like this:

```
[{"field":"time","value":"00:00 - 00:00"},{"field":"heading","value":"sample"},{"field":"description","value":"test test test test test test test test test test test test"},{"field":"details","value":"xxx"}]
```

Comment: Are you sure your DOM is ready when you try to run your script?

Comment: Try wrapping your script in a DOM ready tag as @antyrat suggests. May try to bind too fast on load.

Comment: Also: `$('#day :selected').val()` => `$(this).val()`

Comment: I tried the DOM ready tag like so: `$( document ).ready(function() { //code });` but without any effect

Comment: Can you provide also response JSON example?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly the requested URL has to be on the same Domain like the Referer (including Subdomains like www). In Firefox and Chrome I opened url.com and requested the API at www.url.com. My mistake. Thanks for your Comments!